# User game score ranking

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite

My tool in Django can add users and games and then see them in a table. I want to add the rank, but have no idea how to do it.

```
class BeerPongRankingTable(models.Model):
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', 
    null=False)
    wins = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    games = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(default=date.today)
```

[What my table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeHAV.png).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the rank part of the model? Can you show the template code?

Comment: yes rank is part of the model. I add the code block. You mean the HTML template code ?

Comment: @robinbaehner do you want to change the rank of the records you have?

Comment: @inquirer yes i will that the player with the most wins is on rank 1, the next on rank 2 ….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made views Rank, in which the wins field is sorted in reverse order. Then loop from 1 to the number of rows in the database. At each iteration, i is assigned to aaa[i - 1].rank. The updated data is passed to the dictionary and displayed on the page via the rank_templ.html template. **Replace the 'samplesite' prefix in the 'samplesite/rank_templ.html' line with your application name.**

That is, in my case, when I go to the address: http://localhost:8000/samplesite/rank/

sorting occurs, the database is updated, followed by the display of the page.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("rank/", Rank),
]
```

views.py

```
from .models import BeerPongRankingTable

def Rank(request):
    aaa = BeerPongRankingTable.objects.order_by('-wins')
    for i in range(1, len(aaa) + 1):
        aaa[i - 1].rank = i
        aaa[i - 1].save()
        print('aaa[i].wins', aaa[i-1].wins, type(aaa))
    
    context = {'fff': aaa}

    return render(request, 'samplesite/rank_templ.html', context)
```

rank_templ.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    {% for aa in fff %}
        <p>{{aa.rank}}</p>
        <p>{{aa.username}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: exactly what is in the for loop i was searching. Thank you, so i could solve it!